# How to find the standardized residuals with sklearn?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, linear-regression

Does `sklearn` have a method to get the standardized residuals?
I have created a dataframe with all the values, the predicted values and the residuals.

```
Weight  Height  Sex  Age  PredictedWeight  Residual
81.0    177     0    31   81.2             -0.2
78.2    176     0    28   78.8             -0.6
72.5    172     1    29   71.8              0.7
...     ...     ...  ...  ...               ...
```

The code I have:

```
from sklearn import linear_model
import pandas as pd

X = df[["Height", "Sex", "Age"]]
Y = df["Weight"]

regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr.fit(X, Y)

df["PredictedWeight"] = regr.predict(df[["Height", "Sex", "Age"]])
df["Residual"] = df["Weight"] - df["Predicted"]
```

I would like to add a new column to `df` with the standardized residuals, any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

I think it is simply

```
mean = df["Residual"].mean()
std = df["Residual"].std()

df["StdResidual"] = (df["Residual"] - mean)/std
```

or do you want something else?